# PHP - shell_exec seems like having time limit

Tags: php, shell, time

I'm running a python script while running a php script online. Because of debugging I made one php script:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python ../reader.py");
```

If run it (on linux) with `php test.php` it works and outputs some data. But if I try to access the output on the web, it will give an empty string back.

reader.py takes 8 seconds (so no time limit should be reached).
reader.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11;
pin = 4;

humiture, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

if humiture is not None and temperature is not None:
    print("{\"temperature\": " + str(temperature) + ", \"humiture\":"  + str(humiture) + "}")
else:
    print("fail")
```

Some other commands like `ls` will work always.

I think there is a problem with the duration but how can I pass this issue?

**Solution**:
Solved my problem giving permissions:

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www  
sudo chmod 775 /var/www  
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: This is too unspecific. Show us some code, e.g. where the php script is being called and what it does.

Comment: Make sure that there aren't any issues with paths or file permissions. Start by exclusively using absolute paths. When you call a script using command line, then it will be using the user and environment you're logged in with. If you execute a script through a web server, it will be using the user and environment the web server is using (like www-root when using Apache).

Comment: You should be able to answer the question of timeouts yourself easily, just create a script that takes a certain amount of time.

Comment: Using php `$out = system(....)` might help. It is acting as sequential, so the code will wait till end to populate the $out variable.

Comment: @digijay I updated my post

Comment: @MagnusEriksson absolute paths don't work

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that's interesting! Another python script works with 10 second delay! But what's different?

Comment: @Cryptopat Unfortunately also doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that the user your Web server runs as, and whose permissions the script inherits when it is run from a web page, is not allowed to access the hardware, and returns an empty temperature and humidity - or nothing at all.

Another possibility is that the PHP script executes somewhere else than you think, and finds no reader.py script to launch.

Try using "ls ../reader.py" to see whether the script is accessible, and run

```
"python ../reader.py 2>&1"
```

to also collect any errors from the python spawning. By the way, is the python executable reachable at all? Have you tried an empty reader2.py that only prints "Hello world"?

Comment: *facepalm* oh you are right ^^. Thank you very much. I needed to give www-data permissions. Will update post what I did ^^

Comment: @Husi012 - Instead of updating your post, you should accept this answer.